# closing App and again opening then PopToRootViewController is not Working in swift firebase

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase

I'm new to Swift. I'm working on app. I'm using firebase to register and login user into my app. 
here is my login code:-

```
@IBAction func onClickLogin(_ sender: Any)
{
    let email = Validation.shareValidator.isValidEmail(email: txtEmail.text, view: viewContainerEmail)
    let password = Validation.shareValidator.isValidPassword(password: txtPassword.text, view: viewContainerPassword)
    if email != "success"
    {
        CustomAlert.shareAlert.alertSetUp(title: "Email Field", subTitle: email, boldTitle: "Invalid Email")
    }
    else if password != "success"
    {
        CustomAlert.shareAlert.alertSetUp(title: "Password Field", subTitle: password, boldTitle: "Invalid Password")
    }
    else
    {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: txtEmail.text!, password: txtPassword.text!) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                CustomAlert.shareAlert.alertSetUp(title: "Login Error", subTitle: error!.localizedDescription, boldTitle: "Login Error")
            }
            else
            {
                self.btnLogin.startAnimate(spinnerType: SpinnerType.circleStrokeSpin, spinnercolor: UIColor.white, spinnerSize: 20, complete: {
                    self.btnLogin.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

                    defaults.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")
                    defaults.set(result?.user.uid, forKey: "uid")
                    defaults.set(self.txtEmail.text!, forKey: "email")
                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootTabBarC") as! RootTabBarC
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                })
            }
        }

    }
}
```

here is my register code :-

```
@IBAction func onClickSignUp(_ sender: Any)
{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: txtEmail.text!, password: txtPassword.text!) { (result, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                CustomAlert.shareAlert.alertSetUp(title: "Registration Error", subTitle: error!.localizedDescription, boldTitle: "Registration Error")
            }
            else
            {
                let uid = result?.user.uid
                let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "user").child(uid!)
                ref.setValue(["name" : self.txtName.text!, "email" : self.txtEmail.text!, "password" : self.txtPassword.text!, "mobile" : "", "recipeExpert" : "", "bio" : "", "profileImage" : ""])

                self.btnSignUp.startAnimate(spinnerType: SpinnerType.circleStrokeSpin, spinnercolor: UIColor.white, spinnerSize: 20, complete: {
                    self.btnSignUp.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

                    defaults.set(true, forKey: "isLogin")
                    defaults.set(result?.user.uid, forKey: "uid")
                    defaults.set(self.txtEmail.text!, forKey: "email")
                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootTabBarC") as! RootTabBarC
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                })
          }          
}
```

here is my logout code:-

```
@IBAction func onClickLogOut(_ sender: Any)
{
    do
    {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()

        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "isLogin")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "email")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    }
    catch let err
    {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }

    let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginSignUpVC") as? LoginSignUpVC
    let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc!)
    appDel.window?.rootViewController = navVc
    appDel.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    self.parent?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

}
```

when i'm run my app its working properly, but when i'm close my app recent tab on simulator and open again and try to logout but its not going back to my **LoginSignUpVc** **root view controller**.
there is must problem with **self.parent?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)**

any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when you open your app again, your root view controller is your tabbBar.
you are changing root with login view. it is weird for me to change the root view in the root view and pop to the new root. please make a new storyboard for login and register. and after deleting userDefaults call this code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Authentication", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()

        if let viewController = viewController {
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

you can check userDefaults in appDelegate and lunch correct story board.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    // check your userdefaults and change this codes for loged in user
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Authentication", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginSignupVC")
    //
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

don't forget to set storyboard id for view controller

Comment: @ItsRaju can I see your project? can you mail me?